# Synonymize [date-calculation] to [date-arithmetic]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, synonym-request

Well, [date-arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-arithmetic) and [date-calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/date-calculation) are obviously identical, though the former is a bit more popular and has a tag-wiki.

I hope the synonym meets approval even though I'm fresh out of puns. (Sorry about that.)